# Draggable corners of polygon in compose google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have a map with code:

```
var geoPoints by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<LatLng>()) }
val markers = mutableListOf<Unit>()

GoogleMapView(
    mapGesturesEnabled = mapGesturesEnabled,
    onClick = {
        // onClick
        geoPoints = geoPoints + it
    },
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    onMapLoaded = {
        isMapLoaded = true
        if (!cameraPositionState.isMoving) {
            onBoundsChange(
                cameraPositionState.projection!!
            )
        }
    },
    modifier = modifier
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    if (geoPoints.isNotEmpty()) {
        Polygon(
            points = geoPoints,
            fillColor = Blue2.copy(alpha = 0.1f),
            strokeColor = Blue2
        )

        for (point in geoPoints) {
            val markerState = rememberMarkerState(position = LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
            val marker = Marker(
                state = markerState,
                visible = true,
                icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmapFromImage(context, R.drawable.ic_marker_polygon)),
                draggable = true
            )
            markers.add(marker)
        }

    }
}
```

My idea is to create a map where users can click on the map, for example 3 times, and a polygon will be drawn. But when the user wants to change the polygon dynamically they can drag a corner of this polygon to change its size. Is this possible in compose?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload video again? It's not available. You can convert video to gif and add as image to stackoverflow as well.

Comment: @Thracian I add gif for that issue

Comment: Yeah it is possible, add this in your for scope:  onMarkerDragEnd = { draggedMarkerPosition ->
                    // Update the corresponding geoPoint
                    geoPoints = geoPoints.map { if (it == point) draggedMarkerPosition else it }

Comment: where do you have onMarkerDragEnd in compose? @kasali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.

You were almost there. The key for making this possible is to "observe" the position change of the Marker. When the position of the marker changes you need to update the position of the item in your `geoPoints` list.

I´ve simplified this as much as possible so we can concentrate on the gist of the issue.

```
var geoPoints by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(listOf<LatLng>()) }
val markers = mutableListOf<Unit>()

GoogleMap(
    onMapClick = {
        geoPoints = geoPoints + it
    }
){
    if (geoPoints.isNotEmpty()) {
        Polygon(
            points = geoPoints,
            fillColor = Blue.copy(alpha = 0.1f),
            strokeColor = Blue
        )

        for (point in geoPoints) {
            val markerState = rememberMarkerState(position = LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
            // we are going to observe the change of the marker position here
            LaunchedEffect(markerState.position){
                // get a mutable copy of the List<LatLng>
                val positions = geoPoints.toMutableList()
                // get the index of the dragging point
                val pointIndex = positions.indexOf(point)
                // sanity check
                if(pointIndex < 0) {
                    return@LaunchedEffect
                }
                // update the list with the new value
                positions[pointIndex] = markerState.position
                // assign the copy back and trigger recomposition
                geoPoints = positions
            }

            val marker = Marker(
                state = markerState,
                visible = true,
                draggable = true
            )
            markers.add(marker)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]